# How can I add a search bar with a flat list in react native (no json)?

Tags: react-native

I am building an app, where I have a list and I would like to search the items in the list with a search input how can I do?

```
const videos = [
    {name: 'Unity Pro', link:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7btOci5Gs4&t',key:'1'},
    {name: 'video2', link:'https://www.youtube.com/watchv=K36nOkqjbso&ab_channel=AppleExplained',key:'2'},
    {name: 'video3', link:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7btOci5Gs4&t',key:'3'},

]


const ListVideos = ({navigation}) => {
    return(
(code....)
               <FlatList data={videos}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => {Linking.openURL(item.link)}}>
                <IonIcon name="open-outline" size={16} color="white" style={{justifyContent:"center", alignContent:'center', alignItems:"center", alignSelf:"center", paddingRight:10}}/>
                <Text style={styles.inbuttonText} >{item.name}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            
            >
            </FlatList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TextInput` to filter your list. Set a state for your current variable and a data that will be filtered using your current input text. Something like this.

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState();

//filtering
const searchFilteredData = searchText
    ? flatListData.filter((x) =>
            x.<filterItem>.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
      )
    : flatListData;
```

Then, in your render for TextInput:

```
    <TextInput
        placeholder="Search..."
        style={}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
            setSearchText(text);
        }}
        value={searchText}
    />
```

and your flatlist:

```
    <FlatList
        data={searchFilteredData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
```

change `filterItem` based on your data structure. For example your data looks like this:

```
data = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "John Smith",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "John Willow",
    },
```

use `x.name` in the filter function.

Comment: Since I'm using js you could write it in js, because it gives me an error, thanks

Comment: ` x.<filterItem>.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
      )
    : flatListData; ` Here it says: Type arguments can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8011)

Comment: instead of <filteritem> you put the identifier of your filter. It is all dependent on your structure your data. I modified the answer

Comment: sorry I'm new to this language, I still can't solve it, could we try to use visual studio share? so can you see the full code? because I can't resolve it

Comment: send me your email and we can try it

Comment: cookiedeveloper23@gmail.com